# How to Save PDF currentDestination in Swift

Tags: swift, pdfkit

I am successfully saving the PDF currentDestination using coreData.

(I am saving the data as 'String')

However, how do I 'call' the saved currentDestination via:

```
func go(to destination: PDFDestination)
```

So far, this is what I have:

```
let page = bookmark?.bookmarkPage // this is a 'String'

        pdfView.go(to: page!) // error on "(to: page!)"
```

This is the error I get:

```
Cannot invoke 'go' with an argument list of type '(to: String)'
```

What is the correct way to 'call' the saved PDF currentDestination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you still need help, but, in case you do, you need to pass the pdfView.go(to: ) method a PDFPage object instead of a string. To get a reference to the necessary PDFPage object, try:

```
if let page = self.pdfView.document?.page(at: number) {
   self.pdfView.go(to: page!)
}
```

The 'number' parameter above is an integer, so make sure to convert your saved string into an integer:

```
number = Int(savedStringVariable)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much taking the time to answer my question. I will try this.